# How to fail a Jenkins ant build when TestNG registers unit test failures?

Tags: ant, jenkins, testng

I have a main EAR build script which builds business logic and then runs unit tests like this:

```
<ant antfile="../Project1/build.xml" useNativeBasedir="true" target="test" />
<ant antfile="../Project2/build.xml" useNativeBasedir="true" target="test" />
```

I would like to detect unit test failures and fail the build. I tried `haltOnfailure="false"`. It works but it kills the job on failure in Project1 which means Project2 tests are not run. I would like to ensure both projects are tested.

Answer (score 0):

You want to "fail" the build, but you don't want it to fail on failure and continue testing the second project..... and then fail it.

You will have to capture the return code from both test executions separately, and in the end, do a check if either of them is not 0, i.e. failure, and fail out manually